# defining constexpr variable by checking string condition

Tags: c++, constexpr

```
int run(std::string type, std::string interval)
{
  if(type == "ST"){
    if(interval == "SEC"){
      constexpr unsigned int N = 10;
      Runner<N> data();
      data.parse();
    } else{
      constexpr unsigned int N = 20;
      Runner<N> data();
      data.parse();
    }
  }
  else if(type == "JST"){
    constexpr unsigned int N = 23;
    Runner<N> data();
    data.parse();
  }
  else{
    constexpr unsigned int N = 5;
    Runner<N> data();
    data.parse();
  }
}
```

I want to reduce the if statements and do the conditional checks on a separate function:

```
constexpr unsigned int arraysize(std::string type, std::string interval){
  if(type == "ST"){
    if(interval == "SEC"){
      return 10;
    } else{
      return 20;
    }
  }
  else if(type == "JST"){
    return 23;
  }
  else{
    return 5;
  }
}
```

However this doesn't work because a constexpr function cannot have a parameter of nonliteral type std::string.

Is there a better way to take out conditional checks so that I end up with something like this:

```
int run(std::string type, std::string interval)
{
  constexpr unsigned int N = arraysize(type, interval);
  Runner<N> data();
  data.parse();
}
```

Comment: I'm convinced that `arraysize` should work in C++20 (or, since not all compilers support them yet, change the parameters to `std::string_view`). But `run()` won't be able to call it like this, because function parameters are never considered to be `constexpr` inside of it.

Comment: [OT]: `Runner<N> data();` would be a function declaration... -> `Runner<N> data{};`

Comment: @JasonLiam: Off topic.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run` as you are showing can't work, even in principle, because you want `N` to be runtime-dependent. `N` can't be `constexpr`.

Alternative approach:

```
template<auto V>
inline constexpr auto constant = std::integral_constant<decltype(V), V>{};

template<typename F>
void apply_with_arraysize(F&& f, std::string type, std::string interval){
  if(type == "ST"){
    if(interval == "SEC"){
      f(constant<10>);
    } else{
      f(constant<20>);
    }
  }
  else if(type == "JST"){
    f(constant<23>);
  }
  else{
    f(constant<5>);
  }
}

int run(std::string type, std::string interval)
{
    apply_with_arraysize([](auto N){
        Runner<N()> data; // N instead of N() also ok, if `Runner` doesn't use `auto` non-type template argument
        data.parse();
    }, type, interval);
}
```

Comment: wow the alternative approach contains lots of stuff that I'm not familiar with. If i had to guess, the `constexpr auto constant` allows `N` to be NOT runtime dependent. I would appreciate it if you could help me understand how `std::integral_constant<decltype(V), V>`  makes it non-runtime dependent.

Comment: @MoneyBall `constant` is just a variable template that essentially makes `constant<10>` to be the same as `std::integral_constant<int, 10>{}` which is annoying to write. The point to this is that `std::integral_constant` encodes the value `10` in its _type_. Every instance of the class is stateless, the value we want to use is entirely contained in the type. And so the value can be used as a compile-time constant.

Comment: @MoneyBall The class exports the value again as static member `value`, but it also has a conversion operator to the stored type, so just `N` also works by implicit conversion (assuming the template doesn't use a `auto` non-type template argument, in which case fall back to `N()`. The class also has a `operator()` that returns the encoded value.) See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant, it is very easy to implement, no magic in there.

Comment: this has been so helpful! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, with more overhead, is the `std::variant` approach:

```
std::variant<
    std::integral_constant<unsigned, 10>,
    std::integral_constant<unsigned, 20>,
    std::integral_constant<unsigned, 23>,
    std::integral_constant<unsigned, 5>,
>
arraysize(std::string type, std::string interval){
  if (type == "ST") {
    if (interval == "SEC") {
      return std::integral_constant<unsigned, 10>();
    } else {
      return std::integral_constant<unsigned, 20>();
    }
  } else if (type == "JST") {
    return std::integral_constant<unsigned, 23>();
  } else {
    return std::integral_constant<unsigned, 5>();
  }
}


int run(std::string type, std::string interval)
{
    std::visit(
        [](auto N){
            Runner<N> data{};
            data.parse();
        },
        arraysize(type, interval));
}
```